# Why are extraneous solutions created here?

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

So I understand this trigonmetric identify. I'm just wondering **why** the extraneous solutions are created. What's the intuition?

[image]

I see why we need to square both sides... we can then make use of $sin^2\theta + cos^2\theta = 1$.

But why are the extraneous solutions created?

Comment: In general, any time you square an equation (as you do in step 2) you run the risk of introducing extraneous solutions.  In this case, they correspond to solutions of $\sin \theta + \cos \theta = -1$.

Answer (score 0):

That is simply because
$$A^2=B^2\iff A=B\quad\text{ OR }\quad \color{red}{A=-B}.$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/938103)

Comment: For me, it is a classic explanation of *why*:  because squaring adds a hidden equation, which has its own solutions.